# Android RelativeLayout Simple Cursor Adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, simplecursoradapter

I am using Simple Cursor Adapter to generate views in the adapter.The below is the code to generate views.

```
String[] from = new  String []
{DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_CATEGORY,DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_TASKNAME,DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_CROSSED};

int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2, android.R.id.content};

adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.item_todo, data, from, to,1);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I am getting the below error.

android.widget.RelativeLayout is not a view that can be bounds by this SimpleCursorAdapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="10dip"
android:paddingTop="10dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@android:id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@android:id/icon"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@android:id/icon"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Comment: can you post the xml?

Comment: Post your **item_todo** xml file

Comment: the xml Code is updated above

Comment: For what this is stands android.R.id.content??

Comment: I need to implement draw the line when user swipe from left to right.I checked in the setViewvalue method. i.e in the view i am checking android.R.id.content.

Comment: i think you have implement custom adapter for this.